# Add and remove angular component dynamically

Tags: angular, components

Using ViewContainerRef  and ComponentFactoryResolver we can add and remove angular component dynamically. Here is a sample [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/rjtUlQY4bLDM5H0LJyJb)

```
import {  ComponentFactoryResolver, Injectable, Inject, ReflectiveInjector } 
from '@angular/core'
import { DynamicComponent } from './dynamic.component'
import { AdComponent } from './ad.component';

@Injectable()
export class Service {  
  components = [];
  constructor(private factoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

  public setRootViewContainerRef(viewContainerRef) {
    this.rootViewContainer = viewContainerRef;
  }

  public addDynamicComponent(name, service) {
    const factory = 
    this.factoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(DynamicComponent);    

    let componentRef = this.rootViewContainer.createComponent(factory);    
    this.components.push(componentRef);

    (<AdComponent>componentRef.instance).data = {index: (this.components.length -1), name:name};
    (<AdComponent>componentRef.instance).service = service;     
  } 

  public removeComponent(index) {  
     if (index !== -1) { 
        this.rootViewContainer.remove(index);
        this.components.splice(index, 1);
      }
    }
  }
```

Now my question is, can we do this without service in an easier/best practice or have you any better idea to achieve this?

Comment: ok what is the question?

Comment: okay, then....?

Comment: what do you consider "easier"?  What part of the code you posted is difficult?

Comment: @Claies I wanted to say easier not for understanding, I mean any best practice, any better idea you can provide e.g. parent-child communication by and placing these code in parent component?

Comment: Since it appears that this is functional code, it might be better to post this question on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.  The code review site specializes in reviewing functional code and refining it, while this site focuses on fixing broken code.